# Wrap string without cutting words for thermal printer

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, split

I am trying to print a string by thermal printer, but the problem is that paper accept *only* **32** *charcters in a line* and than break rest text to *another line*, by this last character always *cut into two parts* and string is hard to understand.

Example:

```
string PrintStr = "01-(200),02-(200),03-(200),04-(200),05-(200)";
```

Current output:

```
01-(200),02-(200),03-(200),04-(20            # <- 200 is broken into 20 and 0
0),05-(200)
```

Better output:

```
01-(200),02-(200),03-(200),                  # Split on comma, numbers are preserved 
04-(200),05-(200)
```

I also use a *Linq* mehtod to break line after `32`th character but the *last character* is cutting. I just want after last Comma "," in first 32 characters a new line will be add by that my string will break in *readable text*. I am sharing my code. Thanks in advance for help..

**Input:**

```
var PrintStr = "01-(200),02-(200),03-(200),04-(200),05-(200),06-(200),07-(200),08-(200),09- 
  (200),10-(200),11-(200),12-(200),13-(200),14-(200),15- 
 (200),16-(200),17-(200),18-(200),19-(200),20-(200),21-(200),22-(200),23-(200),24-(200),25-(200),26- 
 (200),27-(200),28-(200),29-(200),30-(200),31-( 
 200),32-(200),33-(200),34-(200),35-(200),36-(200),37-(200),38-(200),39-(200),40-(200),41-(200),42- 
 (200),43-(200),44-(200),45-(200),46-(200),47-(200),48- 
 (200),49-(200),50-(200),51-(200),52-(200),53-(200),54-(200),55-(200),56-(200),57-(200),58-(200),59- 
 (200),60-(200),61-(200),62-(200),63-(200),64- 
 (200),65-(200),66-(200),67-(200),A1111-(200)"
```

**Code** (my attept):

```
var AdjustPrintStr = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, PrintStr
  .ToLookup(c => k++ / 32) 
  .Select(e => new String(e.ToArray())));
```

**Output** (current, *unwanted*):

```
01-(200),02-(200
),03-(200),04-(200),05-(200),06-
(200),07-(200),08-(200),09-(200)
,10-(200),11-(200),12-(200),13-(
200),14-(200),15-(200),16-(200),
17-(200),18-(200),19-(200),20-(2
00),21-(200),22-(200),23-(200),2
4-(200),25-(200),26-(200),27-(20
0),28-(200),29-(200),30-(200),31
-(200),32-(200),33-(200),34-(200
),35-(200),36-(200),37-(200),38-
(200),39-(200),40-(200),41-(200)
,42-(200),43-(200),44-(200),45-(
200),46-(200),47-(200),48-(200),
49-(200),50-(200),51-(200),52-(2
00),53-(200),54-(200),55-(200),5
6-(200),57-(200),58-(200),59-(20
0),60-(200),61-(200),62-(200),63
-(200),64-(200),65-(200),66-(200
```

Note, that the last `"),A1111-(200)"` fragment is *lost*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you have to implement such a routine
(split `text` at `at` characters ensuring at most `maxWidth` characters in each line) *manually*;
it's not that difficult:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> MySplit(string text, 
    int maxWidth, params char[] at) {
  if (null == text)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(text));
  else if (maxWidth <= 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(maxWidth));
  else if (null == at)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(at));

  int startIndex = 0;
  int bestIndex = -1;

  for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; ++ i) {
    if ((i - startIndex) > maxWidth) {
      if (bestIndex < 0)
        bestIndex = i - 1;

      yield return text.Substring(startIndex, bestIndex - startIndex + 1);

      startIndex = bestIndex += 1;
      bestIndex = -1;
    }
    
    if (at.Contains(text[i]))
      bestIndex = i;
  }

  yield return text.Substring(startIndex);
}
```

Now, let's print out the `source` string:

```
string PrintStr = @"01-(200),02-(200),03-(200),04-(200),05-(200),06-(200),07-(200),08-(200),09- 
  (200),10-(200),11-(200),12-(200),13-(200),14-(200),15- 
 (200),16-(200),17-(200),18-(200),19-(200),20-(200),21-(200),22-(200),23-(200),24-(200),25-(200),26- 
 (200),27-(200),28-(200),29-(200),30-(200),31-( 
 200),32-(200),33-(200),34-(200),35-(200),36-(200),37-(200),38-(200),39-(200),40-(200),41-(200),42- 
 (200),43-(200),44-(200),45-(200),46-(200),47-(200),48- 
 (200),49-(200),50-(200),51-(200),52-(200),53-(200),54-(200),55-(200),56-(200),57-(200),58-(200),59- 
 (200),60-(200),61-(200),62-(200),63-(200),64- 
 (200),65-(200),66-(200),67-(200),A1111-(200)";
```

It seems, you should *preprocess* it in order to remove all new lines, tabulations, spaces etc. and
only then split it:

```
// Let's remove all white spaces (new lines, tabulations, spaces)
PrintStr = Regex.Replace(PrintStr, @"\s+", "");

// split on comma ',' while ensuring each lines <= 32 characters 
var result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, MySplit(PrintStr, 32, ','));

Console.Write(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
01-(200),02-(200),03-(200),
04-(200),05-(200),06-(200),
07-(200),08-(200),09-(200),
10-(200),11-(200),12-(200),
13-(200),14-(200),15-(200),
16-(200),17-(200),18-(200),
19-(200),20-(200),21-(200),
22-(200),23-(200),24-(200),
25-(200),26-(200),27-(200),
28-(200),29-(200),30-(200),
31-(200),32-(200),33-(200),
34-(200),35-(200),36-(200),
37-(200),38-(200),39-(200),
40-(200),41-(200),42-(200),
43-(200),44-(200),45-(200),
46-(200),47-(200),48-(200),
49-(200),50-(200),51-(200),
52-(200),53-(200),54-(200),
55-(200),56-(200),57-(200),
58-(200),59-(200),60-(200),
61-(200),62-(200),63-(200),
64-(200),65-(200),66-(200),
67-(200),A1111-(200)
```

Hope, it's the very picture you want to see after printing

Comment: Thank you sir very much this code works very good,but this is through using loop so is this will take too much time to process because i am using this method to mobile app ? Is there is any option using Linq ?

Comment: @Prashant Sharma: *Linq* uses loops as well, so it will *not be faster*; `PrintStr` is a *tiny* string which wiil be processed in microseconds, it's the *termal printer* which will be the bottleneck.